# Natural Deduction - Restriction to closed formulas?

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

Is it typical for formal natural deduction systems to restrict theory axioms and deductions rules to ensure that only closed formulas (formulas with no free variables) appear in proofs? Or is the opposite true? Or does it vary system-by-system?

In a system that requires closed formulas then if we had $((\forall x )(P_x \land Q_x))$ we would be able to prove $((\forall x) P_x)$, but we would not be able to state $P_x\land Q_x$ as an axiom (since it is not closed) and we wouldn't be able to derive something like $(P_x\land Q_x)\implies P_x$.

In a system that does not require closed formulas then it would be straightforward to prove the last formula I mentioned.

I am curious if there is a standard practice in the field for these things. I'd also be interested in specific references which use one approach or the other.

Comment: Natural deduction has no formal defintion, so nothing stops textbook authors from coming up with their own ad-hoc formal systems and calling them "natural deduction". However, the original Gentzen/Prawitz ND systems certainly allowed free variables everywhere. Natural deduction style systems that only have closed formulas are basically unheard of in the mathematical logic literature. Even Hilbert systems that disallow free variables altogether are quite rare, and mostly used only for technical reasons (certain proof-theoretic translations become simpler in the absence of free variables).

Comment: There is no restrictions to "closed" formula; if so, you have to consider that e.g. in order to use the rule of Universal Instantiation it is necessary that the language has at least one individual constant.

Comment: My question is motivated by the introduction on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic). There it say that a Theory is a set of sentences (closed formulas) and the axioms of the theory are a subset of the theory itself, so themselves also sentences. I would then imagine that any proof going from the axioms of the theory to the theorems of the theory could be done with sentences only on every line, having no need for any open formulas.

Comment: I ask because I'm trying to write down, for my own understanding, a particular formal system which we be more natural and easier to work with if theorems only involve closed formulas. This is why I'm interested in references that may also use this approach.